# How to calculate time difference between time ignoring date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am calculation hours between 2 time.

```
var timeDiff = Math.abs(datetime.getTime() - now.getTime());
var diffHours = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600));
```

But PM to AM is issue.

Eg- Start time 9:30 PM and End time is 6:30 AM. 
technically its 2 dates.

From the above code its returning 14 hours, which is correct.

But i want to do just calculate time difference and ignore date. which should be actually 9 hours.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Why not just mod 24 hours?

Comment: I believe what you want is to swap now and previous time, e.g. `var timeDiff = Math.abs(datetime.getTime() - now.getTime());
`

Comment: requirement is to use 12 hours.

Comment: @Andrey swap will return hours in minus.

Comment: mmm .... usually a difference is done by doing end - start . If you get a negative value, it means that your end is before start. Which is consistent with the meeaning of a negative value.

Comment: Provide a set of examples along with expected results. The logic doesn't make a lot of sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date object has more than getTime() function.

Try using getHours(), getMinutes() etc.

[MDN spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 1):

As getTime returns milliseconds, the difference `endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()` will be the correct number of milliseconds (ignoring any problem of timezones) that **you have to spend to go from startDate to endDate** .

Just set your dates correctly. If date time is yesterday at 9:30 PM, then you should not set it as *today* at 9:30 PM, it seems the issue lies more in the initilisation of your dateTime variable.